# Running balance in Sheets - Deduct row from total deposits

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas, running-balance

Sheet 1: I have a list of jobs in column A, for each job there is a charge of $10 in column B unless it was canceled in which case it will display 0. Sheet 2: I have a list of payments and a sum of those payments in cell C1 of Sheet 1. I want to allocate $10 to each row in Sheet 1 and deduct it from balance in column C until it is depleted and obviously include iferror to stop if blank cells.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this in C2 of Sheet1:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",if(sumif(row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A),B2:B)<=Sheet2!C1,B2:B,"Depleted")))
```

Assuming you have $100 in Sheet2!C1, this would give:

[image]